# Eclipse won't open the appearance preference

Tags: android, eclipse

So like many, I had issue's with eclipse and ADT this week. The end result was me having to download ADT again, which solved all the update issues.

I set about setting up my environment again, but when I go to preferences -> general -> appearance I get. The currently displayed page contains invalid values.

I have tried some suggestions, like using a new work space and clearing out the .settings folder. None of this had worked.

It's worth noting that the eclipse logo and the splash screen etc are all the Juno graphics and ADT.

I'm running on mavericks, and have the latest ADT, fully updated. I have also installed the subversive and the moonrise theme.

There was a similar bug to this reported back in 2013, something about subversive and git causing issues with css (It was bit over my head). I looked into and the bug had been marked as fixed.

I'm at a loss of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen multiple reports where third-party themes (such as moonrise) have caused issues. Since your problem is specifically with the Appearance section of the preferences, the moonrise theme seems like a likely culprit. Try uninstalling it to see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: No Joy, it's still doing it